# Why does it say I have "x 2" processor?

Tags: 18.04, cpu

Trying Ubuntu. It says there is have "x 2" processor (View image). What does this mean? I could not find anything online. Please help, thanks

[image]

Comment: your CPU has 2 cores, each has 2.66GHz.

Comment: It means it has two processing cores.

Comment: "Duo" means two.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E7300 has 2 Cores hence the x 2.  See the [Intel data sheet for the processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/36463/intel-core-2-duo-processor-e7300-3m-cache-2-66-ghz-1066-mhz-fsb.html) and [the Wikipedia page for Intel Core 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core_2) for more information about your processor.  Basically, 2 Cores is equivalent to having 2 discrete CPUs on the silicon die.